# Broadcast Receiver not working after reboot android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, reboot

I am using brad cast reciver for detect headset is conncet or not.this my BroadcastReceiver class.

```
class HeadsetIntentReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) {
                val state = intent.getIntExtra(STATE, NEGATIVE_ONE)
                    when (state) {
                        ZERO-> {//Headset  not is plugged
                          
                        }
                         ONE -> {//Headset is plugged
                           
                         }
                     }
            }
        }
    }
```

I register it with this code.

```
registerReceiver(myReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG))
```

that's ok but when device is reboot don't work.I have already checked some the related questions and have not found any solution for this problem. So this is an absolutely new problem for me.

Comment: Well, considering after reboot your app did not run yet, you did not yet register your receiver. You need to either run your app at least once or listen to system boot broadcast and register your receiver then

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the broadcast receiver in the manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name="yourPath.HeadsetIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```